# What is the benefit of adding vegetable oil to cheese cake dough?

Tags: baking, cake, oil, cheese, cheesecake

I recently baked a cheese cake and decided to leave out the oil in the recipe. I expected it to be drier than the one with oil added to the dough but found that this seems not to be the case.

Comment: In what component (the crust or the cheesecake batter) were you supposed to add the vegetable oil? How much oil was it?

Comment: The cheesecake batter; overall one was supposed to add 150 ml of oil.

Comment: Can you share the recipe/link ? i quickly looked at some recipes and they don't have oil in them.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  In order to make it possible for folks to help you, you should share the recipe you're using.

Comment: Hey, without additional detail about the recipe used, we'll have to close this question.